# Unable to execute tcpdump remotely with Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to run tcpdump remotely using [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org).

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip_machine, username='root', password=password)
    my_command = 'sudo timeout 10 tcpdump -i eth0 ip -w somefile'
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(my_command)
    channel = stdout.channel
    channel.recv_exit_status()
    ssh.close()
```

The program exits immediately, despite the `timeout` command and the `recv_exit_status`. The output file of tcpdump is created, but it is empty.

Comment: What do `print stdout.read()` and `print stderr.read()` display?

Comment: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your environment, you cannot run `sudo` from a paramiko connection.

Since you are connecting as `root`, there is no reason for you to run `sudo`. Try this instead:

```
my_command = 'timeout 10 tcpdump -i eth0 ip -w somefile'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the permissions and you ought to use commands with sudo and there are no safety concerns, you can configure `sudo` to execute commands without the requirement of a tty.
On centos the cofiguration file is `/etc/sudoers`, comment the following lines

`Defaults    requiretty` by replacing it with

`#Defaults    requiretty`